# Critique: logo about wifi coverage in a city

Tags: logo, critique

I am designing a logo for a home built app which displays free WiFi coverage in my city. But, because I'm better at programming than designing, I'd like to hear some suggestions. I already have a basic setup.

[image: logo]

It looks a little messy to me but I don't really know what to change. I would like to keep the cell tower, which is surrounded by the canals of my city. I am using GIMP.

Comment: What if you have the wifi tower emerging from the center of the canal shape, with normal wifi signal shapes emitting from it? The multiple-canal thing definitely complicates the image.

Comment: are the canals mirrored in shape like that in reality?

Comment: @DA01 This is based on a real map, just Google for "Leiden"

Comment: The overall shape is great...that does mirror Leiden well and is likely very identifiable. So I think that does work in the context of the people that would see this (which I assume are folks that are in Leiden)

Comment: You might need to normalize the line weights a bit more to make it work at small sizes. Perhaps make the 'inner' wave the same weight as the current middle one, then make the antenna a bit thicker as well. Otherwise I think this will work well as an app icon.

Comment: I wonder how many residents would know what that outline refers to? I certainly couldn't tell you what my city's outline looks like.

Comment: I second @Scott here: I'm Dutch, and have been in Leiden numerous times. Still, I had to be told that these were the canals--I didn't even recognise it as anything beyond so-so-drawn radio waves.

Comment: @scott we obviously can't answer that directly, but note that that is the outline of the major canal in the city. I have a hunch that likely is a very identifiable landmark--though Vincent makes me wonder now. I'd suggest to the OP that they do some informal surveys of locals to see how identifiable the shapes are.

Comment: @DA01 agreed. If it's common for industries in the area to use the canal outline, then it would be fine. But if residents are completely unknowing of the shape, it may be doing more harm than good. Only people living there would know.

Comment: you have to keep it simple. Here's a piece of advice: when designing logos try to design/sketch at small sizes...this way you make sure that the logo will work at any size!

Comment: The intense color contrast and peculiar shape create an optical illusion that the design is undulating like some kind of alien monster... not sure if that is part of the wifi campaign :)

Answer (score -4):

A logo should be simple, clean, and neat. It should be directly representative of your app name.

Here's an example:
[image: logo]

Comment: You should try to curtail your answers to deal directly with the question's content itself instead of providing a generic example. In this case, how can the logo provided in the question be improved?

Comment: There absolutely no need for a logo to directly represent the app name.